# failure of file transfer - is it the file or transfer setting (PC to supercomputer)

Tags: file-transfer, data-transfer

I tried to upload a big file (4Gb) from my PC laptop, through WinSCP program & Ethernet cable, to a Unix-based institution server.

Earlier the same day, I successfully uploaded a 2 Gb file without problems (although the two files have different file extensions. One is .csv (success) and the other .CHRX (failure))

This 4 Gb file, however, cannot be fully uploaded. For unknown reasons, the upload stopped around 500 Mb and I was then prompted to re-enter my password. After entering the password, upload resumed but it appeared that the upload resumed from an early data point (say, 200 Mb) and then when it hit the 500 Mb, it stopped again and asked for password. See below the screenshot for a visual example.

Q1. Is it the file or the file transfer setting of the supercomputer that causes the failure ?

Q2. any solution to upload the full 4 Gb file ?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ramhound, Not sure what specific details will be helpful. Please advise.

Comment: Your description of what you are connecting to, "supercomputer", does not tell me what I need to know to answer your question with regards to the reason you are unable to upload a file from a Windows installation.  The reason the upload stops at a certain size could be any number of things.  Have you asked your IT support staff for assistance?

Comment: @ramhound. common miscommunication :) For a newbie like me, I cannot really know "what an expert needs to know to answer the question". If I know what the problem is, wouldn't I phrase my problem better or find the solution myself?

Comment: You also didn't provide us the settings you are using to upload the file.  Do you have enough space allocated to your account?  This has nothing to do with being a "newbie", provide us with the same information if you were describing this problem to somebody in person.  If you were being asked this question, what information would you require, in order to answer the question?  Your problem isn't that complicated.  There is a simple explanation to the reason the upload stops.

Comment: Thanks. I will check if I have enough space.

Comment: we can agree to disagree, but to me, a newbie is someone who is inexperienced and thus can only see things on a superficial level but also see all issues as equally important, while an expert is someone who sees the same thing but by experience knows what information is important and what's not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think the space in my user account might be the issue. I have cleaned up some junk files and will re-upload the 4 Gb file to see if the upload can now be complete.

Comment: I am by no means an expert.  I knew nothing about the Unix environment your trying to upload to.  I made an educated guess.